# Transition animation in navigation components

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation

I am trying to use shared element transition animation with navigation components, but it is not working, may be I am using it wrongly.

when navigation from Fragment A to Fragment B I did like this:
Fragment A:

```
val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(v to file.nameInStorage)
val action = FilesFragmentDirections.actionFilesFragmentToImageViewerFragment()
findNavController().navigate(action, extras)
```

Fragment B:

```
viewPagerImage.transitionName = filesListViewModel.selectedImage.nameInStorage
```

But unfortunately, it is not working!!! Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

add these transition lines in your nav_graph.xml action inside your navigation package

```
        <action
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/anim1_enter"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/anim1_exit"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/anim2_enter"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/anim2_exit"
        android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_newsFragment"
        app:destination="@id/newsFragment" />
```

code will look like

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:name="com.morchhattisgarh.india.fragments.HomeFragment"
    android:label="fragment_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >

    <action
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/anim1_enter"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/anim1_exit"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/anim2_enter"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/anim2_exit"
        android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_newsFragment"
        app:destination="@id/newsFragment" />

</fragment>
```

Note - you need to defines anims files inside anim package